# Upload SLD file to GeoServer by using gsconfig

Tags: sld, geoserver-rest-api, gsconfig

I want to upload a SLD file, to a specific workspace, by using  [gsconfig-py3 1.0.8](https://pypi.org/project/gsconfig-py3/) , `create_style` function, however I get an error.

```
with open(fpath) as f:
    cat.create_style("railroad", f.read())
```

Error:

```
No such style handler: format = application/xml
```

Style file generated from QGIS as SLD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0"
    <sld:NamedLayer>
        <sld:Name>file_style</sld:Name>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>file_style</sld:Name>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>from</sld:Name>
                    <sld:Title>from</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>from_to</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>from</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#d08760</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</sld:CssParameter>
                            </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:LineSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name>to</sld:Name>
                    <sld:Title>to</sld:Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>from_to</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>to</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#22dc60</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:LineSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:Name/>
                        <sld:Title>from_to is ''</sld:Title>
                        <ogc:Filter>
                            <ogc:Or>
                                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>from_to</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    <ogc:Literal/>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>from_to</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                            </ogc:Or>
                        </ogc:Filter>
                    <sld:LineSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Stroke>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#996bee</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linecap">square</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</sld:CssParameter>
                            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">7</sld:CssParameter>
                        </sld:Stroke>
                    </sld:LineSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: That looks like a correct use of gsconfig - what does the GeoServer log file have to say?

Comment: Your sld file is invalid - the opening StyledLayerDescriptor tag is not closed with`>`

Comment: @IanTurton that was fixed, however it still does not upload the style. It gives a really long list of errors, in java code: 2020-09-07 07:17:34,442 WARN [annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] - Resolved [java.lang.RuntimeException: No such style handler: format = application/xml]
2020-09-07 07:17:54,884 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - No such style: style_layer
org.geoserver.rest.ResourceNotFoundException 404 NOT_FOUND: No such style: style_layer, then the list of java errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working on my machine, which fooled me but then I remembered I had "fixed" my local version of `gsconfig` - you need to change line 894 to `text/xml` from `application/xml`.

I'll try to push my fix to the repository for future users.

Comment: Line 894 in Catalog says "raise ConflictingDataError(msg)"

Comment: quite right - I meant 897 - see https://github.com/quadratic-be/gsconfig-py3/pull/3/files for the full changes